# How to link Bcrypt.lib to VC++ DLL project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, bcrypt, lnk2001, bcrypt.net

Trying to compile a VC++ DLL I get some error messages related to Visual Studio cannot resolve external symbols, errors LNK2001, LNK1120.

In my case the symbol it cannot be resolved is: __imp__BCryptGenRandom@16

and the error message is:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__BCryptGenRandom@16
```

I have googled and found that it is said to link BCrypt.lib so I have linked it at "properties->linker->input->additional dependency"

Also at ""properties->linker->all options->additional library directoris" I have added below one where BCrypt.lib is for x86:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x86
```

And finally at "properties->linker->General->Use library dependencies inputs" I have set "Yes".

But none of these methods work.

Comment: Are you building for x64?

Comment: @heapunderrun my platform is set for x86, not x64

Comment: Okay, I only asked just to be sure there is no accidental mismatch between x86/x64 platform, Debug/Release configuration etc., which tends to be the usual pitfall when configuring Visual Studio projects.

Comment: @Ralph You shouldn't (have to) add any additional library directories, those are correctly set already based on the project choice of target WinSDK. When you added `bcrypt.lib` as a dependency, did you do that for all configs / all platforms? Alternatively, you could also add a line `#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")` in the code, instead.

Comment: @dxiv Honestly I have no experience in VC++. This project it's not mine and I was trying to prepare the environment in my machine to compile it. I have seen it is a DLL project type. So maybe for this type of project library directories are not set up? so it requires me to add it as additional library? Yes, I did, I added bcrypt.lib for all configs/platforms. What does exactly the #pragma directive and where I have to place it in the code?

Comment: @Ralph VC++ can be confusing, the project settings dialog has its config/platform dropdowns which are not sync'd with what's active in the main VS window. [`#pragma comment(lib, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170) "*places a library-search record in the object file*", just like adding the `.lib` in Linker / Input / Additional Dependencies. You can place the `#pragma` in any `.cpp` in the project.